# Opening a specific record from a Access continuous form using SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vba

I have a bit of a problem which I am hoping someone can help with, as I have received excellent help from here before.

I am converting an Access database to SQL Server, and whilst the back end tables have all migrated across, I am having a few problems converting the Access queries to stored procedures.

I think if I can complete the following example, I should be able to go on to convert the rest of the queries.

Basically, I have a form which form which displays all of my records from my CASES table.

I have some search parameters which allow you to filter through these records, which (thanks to this website) works fine.

I am now left with a continuous form, which displays multiple records. On each line of the detail there is a button which runs the following macro.

Open Form

Form name: Cases - Cases (This is a more detailed form, which shows one case per form. The data source for this form is currently a query)

View: Form

Filter Name:

Where Condition: ="[Family ID]=" & [Family ID]

Data Mode:

Window Mode: normal

Now, this does work, it opens up the 'Cases- Cases' form, and shows the correct record based on the 'Family ID'.

The problem being is it is quite slow.

So I have replicated the query in a SQL Server stored procedure, and this works fine.

To compare both the Access query and the stored procedure return all records. The MS Access query runs in around 7 seconds, whereas the stored procedure runs in 1 second.

However, when I set the data source property of the 'Cases - Cases' to the new stored procedure, and continue to use the Macro above above, it is still very slow in opening the form.

So, I think I need a way of restricting my stored procedure to just the 1 record that is selected on the search form.

I could then use VB to set the record selected as a parameter, which is then pushed through to the stored procedure in SQL Server.

I just don't know how to do this part, as it would require the user to still click on the button on the search form, and VB to identify the particular record.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Sample data, desired results would definitely help.

Comment: Are you using a Standard Access query or a SQL Pass-Thru? Also, if there are a lot of records in you Cases table, have you created an Index for [Family ID]?